# I need help in editing the date-time format using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-analysis

I had a data where my time was in UNIX format. I used the following code to convert my time in dataframe to Date format from Unix.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\My Computer\Desktop\Data Analysis\BATS_SPY, 1D.csv')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s')
print(df.head())
```

I get the result as

```
             time
```

0 1993-01-29 14:30:00
1 1993-02-01 14:30:00
2 1993-02-02 14:30:00
3 1993-02-03 14:30:00
4 1993-02-04 14:30:00

What should I do if I only want dates (that is I want to exclude 14:30:00 from the time)

My data was as follows

```
    time
```

0  728317800
1  728577000
2  728663400
3  728749800
4  728836200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your date series:

```
df['date'] = df['time'].dt.floor('D')
```

Comment: It gives me 'AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values'

Comment: Oh, make sure that you're operating on the correct column.

Comment: Ah Gotcha, Thanks!